# What's a good session beer to serve cold?

Tags: temperature

I made an ordinary bitter a while back and it really brought to light why it's served at cellar temperature.  At 55F, it was a bit malty, with nice hops.  At 45F, it was like seltzer. Very drinkable, but why bother?

My kegerator sits at about 45, and I'd like to have a low-gravity and a mid-gravity ale on tap.  What's a session beer that I can serve cold?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  I find I keep all my beers at 45Fish, I find it just covers the whole range of beers I may have in the kegerator.  I think its just easier to pour one and let it warm up to the perfect temp in the glass.

If you have only one tap on your kegerator then serve the beer at its best temp; obviously.  So I assume you have more than one keg in the kegerator. Unfortunately, most session beers are going to be mild and delicate in flavor, so serving at 45F seems out for most of them IMO.

If I had to press myself for a style, I'd lean towards wits and other thirst quenching summer style beers.

Answer (score 1):

At that temp I would probably go for a Weissbier or pilsner. For ales, maybe a citrussy APA or steam beer. My keggerator is at about the same temp, ideally I would like it to be up around 50.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to do a cream ale which would be best served very cold.  Nice hot summer day beer.

Comment: Also, I'd add, RateBeer has a good serving temperature guide:  http://www.ratebeer.com/story.asp?storyid=479

Answer (score 0):

Im a few years late to this party, but I like the answer about fruity ales. I love my blonde ale served at about 40-45. I have to make sure I have at least 1 backup keg ready if my friends are coming over otherwise I run out in a hurry.